# How does this odd domain name even work?

Tags: dns

This domain name should not work, but it does. How is it working?

http://xn--80ahvj9e.xn--p1ai

Is there some htaccess trickery involved here?

I am trying to update disavow.txt for Google's webmaster console. How do I quote such a strange domain name in the list of disavowed links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.%D1%80%D1%84) informs us that **xn--p1ai** is the Cyrillic country code top-level domain for the Russian Federation - in ASCII.

Then, the actual domain name: that's an ASCII rendering of Cyrillic. All those characters are legal values in domain names, so really it should - *and it does* - work. It just doesn't look meaningful, but it probably does in Cyrillic.